# Fitting the MNIST dataset to neural network giving “NotImplementedError”

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, fast-ai

I'm new to PyTorch and I'm using the classic MNIST dataset for image classification.While fitting the model, I'm getting the error :

```
NotImplementedError: uint8
```

I'm using fastai's library's class as a wrapper for all training and validation data and a very basic single-layer neural network. The code I'm using is as follows :

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from fastai.metrics import *

from fastai.model import *

from fastai.dataset import *

import torch.nn as nn

(x_train, y_train), (x_valid, y_valid) = mnist.load_data()

net = nn.Sequential(
  nn.Linear(784,10),
  nn.Softmax()).cuda()

md = ImageClassifierData.from_arrays('/data/mnist', 
(x_train,y_train), 
(x_valid, y_valid))   

loss = nn.NLLLoss()
metrics = [accuracy]
opt=optim.SGD(net.parameters(), 1e-1, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=1e-3)

fit(net, md, n_epochs=3, crit=loss, opt=opt, metrics=metrics)
```

Can someone tell what is this error about and it's solution?

Comment: Could you include the entire trace of the error in your question?

Comment: This was the complete error

Comment: is it possible your input data is in `uint8` format rather than `float32`?

Comment: I also t think that this is a problem of typecasting but what and where do I typecast. I have tried with x_train,x_valid but that didn't seem to work